# How to plot feasible region of nonlinear optimization problem in matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, nonlinear-optimization, inequality

I have a nonlinear, two-variable optimization problem with an inequality constraint.

```
min  f(x,y)
s.t. g(x,y) >= 0
          x >= 0    % y free
```

with

```
a = 0.9;
c = 20; 
h = 5;
j = 1;
l = 1;
m = 10;
s = 3;

f = c.* integral(@(z) (z-x).*normpdf(z,m,s),x,inf,'ArrayValued',true) + h*(y+x-j*m-l*x*(1- normcdf(x,m,s))-l.*integral(@(z) z.*normpdf(z,m,s),-Inf,x));
g = normpdf(x,m,s).*normcdf(y,j*m,sqrt(j)*s) + integral( @(z) normpdf(x-z,m,s).*normcdf(y+z,j.*m,sqrt(j).*s),0,x,'ArrayValued',true) - a;
```

I want to plot the feasible region in a 3D plot to better understand the solution space. What is the best or the most sensible way to do this in Matlab?

I tried to follow the documentation in https://de.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/solve-constrained-nonlinear-optimization-problem-based.html but my problem is not well represented in a contour plot.

Is there a better way to do this or with adaption to a 3D plot?

Comment: Would you please [edit] your question to include the expressions for `f(x,y)` and `g(x,y)`? (see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to Create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex))

Comment: Edits are done, thank you for the hint!

Comment: Thank you.  Are `x` and `y` unrestricted outside of `g(x,y) >=0`?  Also, what are your `a,c,h,j,l,m,s` fixed parameter values?  This would make your example reproducible the thus make it much easier to attempt to help you.

Comment: **Future visitors:** Possibly related https://stackoverflow.com/q/42141543/8239061

Comment: Thanks again, edited accordingly.